# How to order the column value in sql?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do results from a SQL query not come back in the order I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999913/why-do-results-from-a-sql-query-not-come-back-in-the-order-i-expect)

I have table like this..My table name  is pattern.

```
S.No      type      Id_Section
    1          A        IPS
    2          A        IPS
    3          A        IPS
    4          A        IPS
    1          B        IPS
    2          B        IPS
    3          B        IPS
    1          C        IPS
    2          C        IPS
    5          A        IPS
    4          B        IPS
```

In this table, last row has unordered.So
I need to order table where serialno, and type = 'A'
 ..
After ordering,
For example I should display like this

```
S.No      type      Id_Section
    1          A        IPS
    2          A        IPS
    3          A        IPS
    4          A        IPS
    5          A        IPS
    1          B        IPS
    2          B        IPS
    3          B        IPS
    4          B        IPS
    1          C        IPS
    2          C        IPS
```

How to write a sql query for this?Please anyone help me

Comment: shree, I think that maybe you will need to communicate more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.  I think it's very possible that you are wanting something more complex than what you seem to be asking.  Also, we all read the comments you post on other people's answers, so there's no need to repeat yourself 5 times to everyone.

Comment: downvoting for sheer laziness - a simple goog on "sql column order by" would tell you the answer

Comment: @shree: Please read the [FAQ] before posting further. You are more than likely going to be banned for posting too many low quality questions.

Answer (score 15):

From your comment to Mithun Sasidharan and Connell Watkins

> Hi Here i need to specify type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

It seems you want to map values to a certain order. Without adding a `Sort order` field or table you can use a `CASE`. Even then their are two approaches

**Map each value**

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN Type = 'INL' THEN 0
        WHEN Type = 'BRL' THEN 1
        WHEN Type = 'CRS' THEN 2
   END
```

**Bring just the one to the top**

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN Type = 'INL' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
   END,
   Type
```

Comment: This is giving me duplicate records on pagination. Any way to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 3):

Specify ascending or descending for each column

```
SELECT * FROM PATTERN ORDER  BY S.No ASC;
```

Comment: Hi Here i need to specify  type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

Comment: @shree : So if you want to oder it based on Type u can specify that also... both Thpe and S.no or just Type as per your need!!

Comment: Hi I tried like this...                                                       SELECT * FROM 'pattern' ORDER BY type = 'A' and type = 'B' and type = 'c' and s.no...But i am getting 0 records

Comment: just give SELECT * FROM 'pattern' ORDER BY type ASC

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table order by type ASC, s.no ASC
```

Comment: Hi Here i need to specify  type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM Table [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) type

Comment: Hi Here i need to specify  type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

Comment: Hi I tried like this...                                                       SELECT * FROM 'pattern' ORDER BY type = 'A' and type = 'B' and type = 'c' and s.no...But i am getting 0 records

Comment: @shree your answer seems to indicate that you need a custom sort. You should edit your answer to include that information if that's what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Add `order by type` to your query

Comment: Hi Here i need to specify  type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pattern ORDER BY 2,1
```

Comment: Hi Here i need to specify  type = 'A' and type = 'B'..i mustspecify type..Coz in my table A , B,C are "INL", "BRL" ,"CRS"..So Ishould specify the type..How to do that..Please tell me

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!